# JQuery Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in using Ajax reponse

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

> [{"ContainerNo":"FCIU3554053","Size":20,"SealNo":"172003","Weight":25209.00},{"ContainerNo":"TEMU5422909","Size":20,"SealNo":"164169","Weight":25400.00}]

```
 $.ajax({
       url: "/Popu/GetContainers",
       dataType: "json",
       complete: function (response) {
           var parsedJson = JSON.parse(response.responseText);

           var thead = '', tbody = '';
           //for (var key in parsedJson[0]) {
              // thead += '<th>' + key + '</th>';
           //}
          thead += '<th>ContainerNo</th><th>Size</th><th>SealNo</th><th>Weight</th>';

          $.each(parsedJson, function (i, d) {
             tbody += '<tr><td>' + d.ContainerNo + '</td><td>' + d.Size + '</td><td>' + d.SealNo + '</td><td>' + d.Weight + '</td></tr>';
          });

          callback($('<table style="padding-left:20px;">' + thead + tbody + '</table>')).show();
  }
```

I am getting the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length'. I am very confused. I get the same error when doing - parsedJson.Count.

Comment: *"...I get the same error when doing - parsedJson.Count* Your code has `parsedJson.count.`, not `parsedJson.Count` (capitalization matters), and arrays don't have either a `count` or a `Count` property (they have a `length` property), and accessing a non-existant property wouldn't give you the "same error."

Comment: *"I am getting the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length'."* All due respect, I'm fairly sure you're not. Please use copy and paste to show the **actual** error you're getting.

Comment: Using `for-in` to get your column headers is incorrect. First off, there is no defined order to `for-in` loops. Second off, you're defining the order of your columns later in your `$.each` loop as specifically ContainerNo and then Size. So since that's hardcoded, hardcode your column labels as well.

Comment: Ok, I have removed the Count and changed the labels to hard-coded but am getting the same error at line:  $.each(parsedJson, function (i, d) {  see above code change

Answer (score 0):

First, you have an `Array` of objects:

```
var foo = '[{"ContainerNo":"FCIU3554053","Size":20,"SealNo":"172003","Weight":25209.00},{"ContainerNo":"TEMU5422909","Size":20,"SealNo":"164169","Weight":25400.00}]';
```

Note:  `string` (enclosed in single quotes) to justify using `JSON.parse`, otherwise, if the response were already an `Array` then you don't need to parse.

```
var parsed = JSON.parse(foo)

// iterate over your array
for(i = 0; i < parsed.length; i ++){
    console.log(`Container No: ${parsed[i].ContainerNo}, Seal No: ${parsed[i].SealNo} `);
}
```

Output:

```
Container No: FCIU3554053, Seal No: 172003
Container No: TEMU5422909, Seal No: 164169
```

If you want to use [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
parsed.forEach( i => console.log(`Container No: ${i.ContainerNo}, Seal No: ${i.SealNo} `));
```

Output:

```
Container No: FCIU3554053, Seal No: 172003 
Container No: TEMU5422909, Seal No: 164169
```